# Scrapy Mongodb pipeline timeout

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

i am using `scrapy` and implement `mongodb` pipeline,

but recently I found out when I have a lot of item, some item will get

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: x.x.x.x:27017: timed out
```

Is each item, it will open the mongoclient connection and close.
Can we open a connection for whole `scrapy` to increase the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, opening new connection for each item appear to be not resource-effective. This tutorial shows exactly how to do one connection per crawler.
https://realpython.com/web-scraping-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/